# How to disable vcstime

Tags: linux, debian, bash, terminal, console

There's a program /usr/sbin/vcstime which prints the date/time in the top/right corner of your terminals. You can enable it in /etc/kbd/config (on the last line). It's disabled by default.

I'm having a problem whereby each time I ssh into one of my servers (Debian Jessie) vcstime runs. I don't know why it is running. My /etc/kbd/config file does not enable it.

I moved /usr/sbin/vcstime to /usr/sbin/vcstime.disabled. I rebooted. And still I have the problem. I grepped for 'vcst' and didn't find anything interesting. I have no idea why the clock is always printed in my terminal. It's getting in the way of some content that always prints on the top line and I need to make it go away.

Can anyone help with that?

Note: if I run `/etc/init.d/kbd restart` the clock disappears for a second then reappears.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Turns out I had the following code in my .profile...

`while true; do echo -ne "\e[s\e[0;$((COLUMNS-37))H$(date)\e[u"; sleep 1; done &`